# Creating a list without a trailing comma

Tags: bash, shell

Currently I use the following command to export the environment variable `FOO`:

```
export FOO=$(for i in {0..7}; do echo -n "uops_dispatched_port.port_$i|p$i,"; done)
```

This results in the string:

```
uops_dispatched_port.port_0|p0,uops_dispatched_port.port_1|p1,uops_dispatched_port.port_2|p2,uops_dispatched_port.port_3|p3,uops_dispatched_port.port_4|p4,uops_dispatched_port.port_5|p5,uops_dispatched_port.port_6|p6,uops_dispatched_port.port_7|p7,
```

I'd like a similarly simple, DRY, command that results in the same string without the trailing comma.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the parameter expansion to remove the trailing comma eg.:

```
foo=$(for i in {0..7}; do echo -n "uops_dispatched_port.port_$i|p$i,"; done)
export FOO=${foo%,}
```

Below is the fragment from [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) that describes this construct:

> ${parameter%word}
>   ${parameter%%word}
>
> The word is expanded to produce a
>   pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see
>   [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)). If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the
>   expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the
>   value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case)
>   or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. If parameter
>   is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each
>   positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
>   If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the
>   pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: @BeeOnRope You can replace the new line with `;`.

Comment: Bam, you got me :)

Answer (score 2):

Me too!

```
export FOO=$(seq 0 7 | xargs -I{} echo "uops_dispatched_port.port_{}|p{}" | paste -sd,)
```

- `seq` generates numbers from 0 to 7
- `xargs -I{}` outputs the number in the strange format requested.
- `paste -sd,` joins the lines with the comma.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the for-loop output to `head -c-1` to delete the trailing comma:

```
export FOO=$(for i in {0..7}; do echo -n "uops_dispatched_port.port_$i|p$i,"; done | head -c-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
export FOO=$(a=(); for i in {0..7}; do a+=("uops_dispatched_port.port_$i|p$i"); done; IFS=,; echo "${a[*]}")
```

The assignment to `IFS` is limited within the subshell and does not affect the following statements.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
export foo=$(awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=7;i++)printf "%suops_dispatched_port.port_%d|p%d",(i>1?",":""),i,i}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one is using read and PE directly inside the command substituion.

```
export foo=$(read -r var < <(for i in {0..7}; do printf '%s' "uops_dispatched_port.port_$i|p$i,"; done); printf '%s' "${var%,}" )
```

Or use the good ol pipe with command grouping using braces `{ }`

```
export foo=$(for i in {0..7}; do printf '%s' "uops_dispatched_port.port_$i|p$i,"; done | { read -r var ; printf '%s' "${var%,}" ; } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the comma at the end of each `echo` string (and then removing the last one), print the comma at the beginning of the `echo` string for the 2nd thru 7th passes through the loop ...

- remove comma (`,`) from `echo` command
- set variable `dl=""` for first pass through loop
- print `${dl}` at beginning of `echo` string
- set `dl=","` at end of loop so that ...
- on successive passes through the loop the `echo` string starts with a comma (`,`)

This gives us:

```
$ export FOO=$(dl="" ; for i in {0..7}; do echo -n "${dl}uops_dispatched_port.port_$i|p$i"; dl=","; done)
$ echo $FOO
uops_dispatched_port.port_0|p0,uops_dispatched_port.port_1|p1,uops_dispatched_port.port_2|p2,uops_dispatched_port.port_3|p3,uops_dispatched_port.port_4|p4,uops_dispatched_port.port_5|p5,uops_dispatched_port.port_6|p6,uops_dispatched_port.port_7|p7
```

**NOTE**: I just noticed this is the same logic Kent's using in his answer; I've opted to use the hardcoded assignments to variable `dl` as opposed to the conditional test that Kent uses; same logic (different implementation) and same results ...

Answer (score 0):

Also you can mark it as the last one and remove precisely

```
export FOO=$(for i in {0..7}; do echo -n "uops_dispatched_port.port_$i|p$i,"; done; printf "_LAST_")
echo ${FOO//,_LAST_/}
```